# How to make div for whole size from top to bottom

Tags: css, html, size

I have this kind a scenario:

```
<div id=area>
 <div id=box>
 </div>
</div>
<div id=footer>
</div>
```

div "area" is center and it is 700px width and has shadows at right and left. 
there is then a div box, which is 500px width and has text and options in it.
And at bottom I have footer where is one line of text.

So, my shadow effect at div "area" stops at same spot as box does. At next page, i have ~2000px amount of text in same box, and there "area" div's shadow is as it should be.

I want to have "area" div whole screen size, and more if there is more text inside of it.

Comment: Show more code (specially css) or example

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="area">
   <div id="box">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
   html {height:100%} 
   body {height:100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;} 
   #area {height: 100%;background-color: blue}
```